# perf : How to check processess running on particular cpu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

Is there any option in perf to look into processes running on a particular cpu /core, and how much percentage of that core is taken by each process.

Reference links would be helpful.

Comment: I tried : perf top -C <cpu-list>, its giving kernel functions on cpu interms of percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perf` is intended to do a profiling which is not good fit for your case. You may try to do sampling `/proc/sched_debug` (if it is compiled in your kernel). For example you may check which process is currently running on CPU:

```
egrep '^R|cpu#' /proc/sched_debug 
cpu#0, 917.276 MHz
R          egrep  2614     37730.177313 ...
cpu#1, 917.276 MHz
R           bash  2023    218715.010833 ...
```

By using his PID as a key, you may check how many CPU time in milliseconds it consumed:

```
grep se.sum_exec_runtime /proc/2023/sched
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :        279346.058986
```

---

However, as  @BrenoLeitão mentioned, [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) is quite useful for your script. Here is script for your task.

```
global cputimes;
global cmdline;
global oncpu;

global NS_PER_SEC = 1000000000;

probe scheduler.cpu_on {
    oncpu[pid()] = local_clock_ns();
}

probe scheduler.cpu_off {
    if(oncpu[pid()] == 0)
        next;

    cmdline[pid()] = cmdline_str();
    cputimes[pid(), cpu()] <<< local_clock_ns() - oncpu[pid()];

    delete oncpu[pid()];
}

probe timer.s(1) {
    printf("%6s %3s %6s %s\n", "PID", "CPU", "PCT", "CMDLINE");
    foreach([pid+, cpu] in cputimes) {
        cpupct = @sum(cputimes[pid, cpu]) * 10000 / NS_PER_SEC;

        printf("%6d %3d %3d.%02d %s\n", pid, cpu, 
            cpupct / 100, cpupct % 100, cmdline[pid]);
    }

    delete cputimes;
}
```

It traces moments when process is running on CPU and stops execution on that (due to migration or sleeping) by attaching to `scheduler.cpu_on` and `scheduler.cpu_off` probes. Second probe calculates time difference between these events and saves it to `cputimes` aggregation along with process command line arguments.

`timer.s(1)` fires once per second -- it walks over aggregation and calculates percentage. Here is sample output for Centos 7 with `bash` running infinite loop:

```
     0   0 100.16 
    30   1   0.00 
    51   0   0.00 
   380   0   0.02 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
  2016   0   0.08 sshd: root@pts/0 "" "" "" ""
  2023   1 100.11 -bash
  2630   0   0.04 /usr/libexec/systemtap/stapio -R stap_3020c9e7ba76838179be68cd2390a10c_2630 -F3
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that perf is not the proper way to do it, although you can limit `perf` per CPU, as using  `perf record -C <cpulist>` or even `perf stat -c <cpulist>`.

The close you are going to see is the `context-switch` event, but, this is not going to provide you the application names at all.

I think you are going to need something more powerful, as systemtap.